# Shrink a Bulk insertion into a loop-based

Tags: sql, sql-server

Want to change this piece of SQL query into a loop version which
Could `Select-Insert` records **by 1000 items** per iteration.

On each iteration want to get a print to see what was the last inserted item.

**The Code :**

```
INSERT INTO [tData2]
(
    [Key], 
    Info1,
    Info2
)
SELECT 
    [Key], --the Id
    Info1,
    Info2
FROM
    [tData]
```

**Edit :**

(There were other conditions to limit the insertion, which aren't related to the question)

The Bulk-Insertion logic will not be changed, just we shrink the database pieces to be inserted.
Instead of inserting the whole table we Bulk-Insert 10000 items per iteration and could get a simple report on it also.

your help is really appreciated.

Comment: What's the question ? What have you tried?

Comment: You can implement this using cursors and/or server-side paging style code via row_number()

Comment: Want to change it into a While loop with a selection of 1000 items per iteration, most of the codes I saw didn't meet this scenario. That way could get a simple print report on each Iteration.

Comment: @mellodev you are right, about the both solutions you mentioned couldn't find the simple relevant piece of code meet this problem, could you please provide a simple snippet on this ?

Comment: In most of examples on loops there were some suggestions on avoiding cursors as possible, Here are them the best option doing this piece of work or what else will you suggest on this ?

Comment: Are you using the identity field?Also, why would you want to change a bulk load to slower insert -select?Any specific business requirement?

Comment: @Gulli Meel Wasnt sure on that, I wanted to make the Select-Insert task by 1000 items , cause doing that on the whole table which I have 200,000 records was really time-Consuming, Heard that narrowing the selection will increase it's performance, also thinking of getting a simple report on the iterations to see what record is inserting at the moment, If you are saying that this would be the slow version of it, please provide me a solution, how to narrow the selection on bulk insertion with or without a loop, I think here we could do the Bulk insertion on each 1000 items and not the whole table

Comment: There are many different ways to do what you want, cursors/batched loading are just one approach. Only you will be able to tell what is right for your situation.

Comment: You are not narrowing the selection but you are doing it in batches.If you are selecting from other tables to insert into this table( which i can see is the case) then check the plan for the select statement from the table and see if it could be tuned further to reduce the time taken to get the data. Also, what kind of indexes do you have on table in which you will insert the data? The optimizer might sort the data which will go into the table to make sure that there are very less page splits. Thus you have to post the plan of insert-select for full rows.Then only something could be suggetsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some sample code I quickly put together for you to experiment with. This doesn't use a cursor (uses while instead) but you could build it that way as well. There are some performance optimizations that you could make but only you can judge that. YMMV

```
    set nocount on

/* mock up source/dest tables */
declare @src table (id int, value varchar(max));
declare @dest table (id int, value varchar(max));

/* fill source with some data */
declare @rownum int;
set @rownum=0;
while (@rownum<5000) begin
    insert into @src select @rownum,'test value ' + CONVERT(varchar(25),@rownum);
    select @rownum=@rownum+1;
end

/* laod batched data */
declare @pagesize int;set @pagesize=1000;
declare @rowlow int;set @rowlow=0;
declare @rowmax int;set @rowmax=@pagesize;

declare @ct int;select @ct = COUNT(*) from @src;
declare @id int;
declare @value varchar(max);

while (@rowmax<=@ct) begin

    WITH result_set AS (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS [row_number], id,value
      FROM @src  
    ) insert into @dest 
        SELECT id,value FROM result_set
        WHERE [row_number] BETWEEN @rowlow AND @rowmax

    -- Output
    print 'Copied rows ' + convert(varchar(25),@rowlow) + ' to ' + convert(varchar(25),@rowmax)     

    -- Increment batch counters
    select @rowlow=@rowmax+1,@rowmax+=@pagesize;
end

select * from @dest
```